# I am working on the tridion. Everytime when you click a link (menu )it creates a new session. Backend we are using tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, tridion, tridion-content-delivery

I am using SDL Tridion to publish JSP pages to our Tomcat Application server. Every time I click on a link to another page it creates a new session. How can I prevent new sessions from being created for every page view?

Comment: please post your jsp page code.

Comment: Please specify the version of Tridion you are using

Comment: In current state, your question is pretty poor. Please post more details, code sample, explanation of what happens and what you think it should happen instead and of course more information on what you tries and how/why that failed.

Comment: I've also down-voted the question. Please take this positively. What it means is simply that in order to have people help you, and leave behind a good question and answer for future reference, you need to make sure the question is clear and contains all the relevant information (and perhaps make sure that irrelevant details are removed). If you fix the question, it will be upvoted again.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the session creation  by setting `session=false`

For more description check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515729/why-set-a-jsp-page-session-false-directive) once