# JSP Servlet session invalidate() does not make session null

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, httpsession

I have three simple HttpServlet classes in my JSP project, "LoginServlet", "LogoutServlet" and "ProfileServlet".

- LoginServlet: log in user by setting "name" attribute to session
- LogoutServlet: log out user and invalidate session
- ProfileServlet: display user welcome info if user has logged in

The last two servlets are as below that I reckon are problematic.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

            HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
            session.invalidate();

            request.getRequestDispatcher("link.jsp").include(request, response);

            out.print("You are successfully logged out!");

            out.close();
    }
}
```

And

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ProfileServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("link.jsp").include(request, response);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");

            out.print("Hello, " + name + " Welcome to Profile");
        } else {
            out.print("Please login first");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request,
                    response);
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And the link.jsp:

```
<% HttpSession nsession = request.getSession(false);
if(nsession == null) {
%>
<a href="login.html">Login</a>
<%
}
else {
%>
<a href="LogoutServlet">Logout</a>
<%
}
%>
<a href="ProfileServlet">Profile</a>
<hr/>
```

The problem is while user is logged in, when the "Logout" link is clicked and "LogoutServlet" is called, session is not correctly invalidated and ProfileServlet still prints out

```
"Hello, null Welcome to Profile"
```

instead of redirecting to the "login.html" page because the session is still NOT null. As a result of it, "Login" link is not shown on the "link.jsp" page. This stops the user from being able to attempt to log in again.

***EDIT:***
To make the problem clarified, I made a new html page and updated the servlets to do

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);
```

And the "link.html".

```
<a href="login.html">Login</a>
<a href="LogoutServlet">Logout</a>
<a href="ProfileServlet">Profile</a>
<hr/>
```

Interestingly this does what I wanted! I guess the problem is

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("link.jsp").include(request, response);
```

But I am unable to explain why...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JSP new session is created by default, if non present, so you will always get non null session. You can disable that by adding following page directive to your page:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

For more info check the following [Why set a JSP page session = “false” directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5515729/3701228)

Comment: Thanks Gas. That is what I wanted!:)

Answer (score 3):

When it calls [`invalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29) it removes that session from server context and all associated data with that session,

When you make new request it creates new one and so you see `null` as the data because new session doesn't have data in it

You should check for a logical attribute inside `session` to validate it user is logged in or not, instead of session itself

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! But I wanted to make session null instead of creating a new session that has no data associated with it. I think `request.getSession(false)` is get the current session rather than creating a new one, isn't it?

Comment: when you make new request to server, it creates session if not already associated found

Comment: because you aren't creating new request, you are just forwarding same request to new resource

Comment: Thanks Jigar. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

That may help You Check it out for condition checking.

Condition To Check:

```
<%
if (session.getAttribute("name") == null || 
session.getAttribute("name").equals(""))
{
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
%>
```

Set Up While Logout:

```
session.setAttribute("name", "");
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```