# session created before initializing it

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, servlet-filters

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MJ Page</title>
</head>
<body align="center" bgcolor="#FF7C7C">

<h1 align="center" style="padding-bottom:20rem;"> Welcome to MJ Page</h1>
<h2 style="padding-bottom:4rem; padding-left:2rem;"> Login Form </h2>
<form action="login" method="post">
    Email Id <input type = "text" name="emailid" required/><br/><br/>
    Password <input type = "password" name="pass" required/><br/><br/>
<input type  = "submit" role="button">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Loginfilter.java

```
package com.linuxx;

import java.io.*;


import javax.servlet.*;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
@WebFilter("/login")
public class Logmport javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.inFilter implements Filter {
       
 
    
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        System.out.print(session==null);


    }

}
```

Initially I go to localhost:8080/DemoApp/home.jsp but I didn't create any session in that, but the session is created somehow and when I print (session==null) it shows false
but its supposed to return true.I even tried restarting the server... help!

Comment: If you don't want a session to be automatically created, then add attribute  session="false"  to home.jsp page directive.

Comment: How to add to make it false? by setAttribute method? @rickz

Comment: @rickz I tried invalidating the session but its not working

Comment: Just add the attribute to the directive. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789857/how-session-gets-create-in-jsp

Comment: @rickz it didn't work

Comment: i was just checking if the session was null then I started checking if getAttribute("email") equals null that was easy to do it.. thanks anyway @rickz

Comment: That attribute should work and tell  home.jsp not to create a session. Your form action is going to  a Filter. That is not right. You should use a JSP or a Servlet as endpoint.