# Session created by Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am learning session with servlets and i read in the book that to create a session we need to call as below.

`HttpSession session = request.getSession()`

This causes the web container to create a session ID and send it back to client so that client can attach it with every subsequent request to the server. When i open developer tools in chrome under request headers in network tab i do see a cookie header.

`Cookie: JSESSIONID=F92`

Below is what i did in my login servlet

```
package shop;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String uid = request.getParameter("uid");
        String password = request.getParameter("pwd");
        
        if(uid.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin"))
        {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            System.out.println(session.getId());
            response.sendRedirect("shopping");
        }
        else
            response.getWriter().println("Invalid Credentials");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        this.doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>shopping application</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:cyan">
<div style="text-align:center">
<h3>Welcome to Mart</h3>
<form action="login" method="post" name="loginform">
    <div style="padding:2px;">
        <label for="uid">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="uid" name="uid">
    </div>
    <div style="padding:2px;">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is that even if i remove the `getSession()` call i still see the cookie in the network tab. Is there a default session associated with every request by tomcat?

Comment: Do you have authentication enabled?

Comment: I am new to all this, how can i check that? I am using tomcat from eclipse to run my project

Comment: With authentication enabled you need to provide a username and password when accessing the page.

Comment: I do take username and password as input from index.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Tomcat sessions are established lazily, when they are needed. There are basically a couple of situations where sessions are created:

- if you call `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(true)` a session is always established,
- if you authenticate users against Tomcat's user database a session might be created depending on the authentication method. Most notably if you use form authentication (see [this tutorial](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-form-authentication-with-tomcat.html)) a session is **always** established,
- JSP pages create sessions unless you add the `<%page session="false"%>` directive (see [Why set a JSP page session = "false" directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5515729/11748454)).

Browsers remember cookies, so the presence of a `JSESSIONID` is not an indication of the presence of a session (it might be there from a previous test). To test for a presence of a session use `request.getSession(false)`. For example:

```java
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      final boolean establishSession = req.getParameter("withSession") != null;
      try (final PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter()) {
         final String requestedSessionId = req.getRequestedSessionId();
         final HttpSession possibleSession = req.getSession(establishSession);
         writer.append("I requested a session with id: ")//
               .append(requestedSessionId)
               .append("\nI have a session with id: ")
               .append(possibleSession != null ? possibleSession.getId() : null)
               .println();
      }
   }
```

**Edit:** I added the case of a JSP page creating sessions.

Comment: I made absolutely no changes in web.xml for setting up authentication, is it only because i am using form?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your JSP page code. So yes, your JSP page with the form creates the session, you need to add `session="false"` to the `page` directive (see the revised answer).